# Fetch Foreign key object from an api using reactjs

Tags: python, django, api, reactjs, tastypie

I am so confused and it is becoming very difficult for me to carry on my project. I am developing rental system application where user can register their space(includes ownername,listingname,email,summary,multiple images of their room and etc).I have created two table for this. One for rental details and another gallery for multiple images for one rent. 
I created an api resource for both. I could save data to my database also.I succeed in fetching rental details using reactjs and tastpyie but i could not fetch image associated with that rental.What should i do for this?

**Models.py**

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    ownerName = models.CharField(_("Owner's Name"),max_length=255, blank=True,null=True,
        help_text=_("Owner's Full Name"))
    listingName =  models.CharField(_("Lisitng Name"), max_length=255, blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Title of the rental space"))
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True,null=True,help_text=_("Description of the rental space"))
    room = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("No of Rooms"), blank=False, null=True,
        help_text=_("Number of bedrooms available"))
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Rental price of the space per month"))

    def save_images(self, images,instance):
        for image in images:
            GalleryImage.objects.create(image=image, rental=instance)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.listingName


class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    rental = models.ForeignKey('Rental',on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True,
                                verbose_name=_('Rental'), related_name="gallery")
    image = models.FileField(blank=True,upload_to='upload/',null=True)
```

**api.py**

```
class MultipartResource(object):
    def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
        if not format:
            format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
        if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            return request.POST
        if format.startswith('multipart'):
            data = request.POST.copy()
            data.update(request.FILES)
            return data
        return super(MultipartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)

    def put_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE').startswith('multipart') and \
                not hasattr(request, '_body'):
            request._body = ''
        return super(MultipartResource,self).put_detail(request,**kwargs)

    def patch_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', '').startswith('multipart/form-data') and not hasattr(request, '_body'):
             request._body = ''
        return super(MultipartResource, self).patch_detail(request, **kwargs)

class RentalResource(MultipartResource,ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Rental.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rental'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post','put']
        fields = ['listingName','ownerName','room','price','summary']
        filtering = { "property" : ALL , "room":ALL,"price":ALL}
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

class GalleryImageResource(ModelResource):
    rental = fields.ForeignKey(RentalResource, 'rental')
    class Meta:
        queryset = GalleryImage.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'gallery'
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put']
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

**reactjs code for fetching data**

```
export default class RoomList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { rooms: [] }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('componentDidMount');
        this.loadRoomFromServer();
    }

    loadRoomFromServer(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/api/v1/rental/',
            dataType:'json',
            success: (data) => {
                console.log('data',data);
                this.setState({rooms: data.objects});
                console.log('success');
              },
              error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                console.error(url, status, err.toString());
              }
            });
    }

    render(){
        console.log('rooms',this.state.rooms);
        let listOfRoom = this.state.rooms.map((room,id)=>{
            return(
                    <Rooms key={id} name={room.listingName} price={room.price} number={room.room} />
                )
        });
        console.log('listOfRoom',listOfRoom);
        return(
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                            { listOfRoom }
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
    }
}

class Rooms extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
                    <p>{this.props.price}</p>
                    <p>{this.props.number}</p>
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

as the url will be different for rental and gallery how could i now fetch images associated with that rent?
Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: In your serializer, include the URL associated with the file object (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/)). That way, you can just inject it into the src attribute of the img tag.

Comment: The images are uploaded with different id how can i associate multiple images to its rent.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand which url you are talking about . Do you mean to say upload_to  from the docs?

Comment: If you want to get the image from the rental, you'll do something like rental.galleryimage_set.all()

Comment: No, the image has an attribute url, so galleryimage.image.url

Comment: Side note: use the ImageField for storing the image itself.

Comment: Where should I inject image attribute URL in serializer?

Comment: Not really an expert in Tastypie but you need to add a method for making a URL out of the file name (the url method on the file object uses the Storage class to build it). I looked around for it a bit but didn't find anything too specific but I would start out there.

Comment: Could you provide me the link of such technique? I am not well versed at API . I will try to go deeper onto it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=relationships#reverse-relationships

Tastypie doesnt automatically add relationship fields, you need to do them manually.

If you want to hit the rental endpoint and get related gallery resources, do the following:

```
class RentalResource(MultipartResource,ModelResource):
    gallery = fields.ToMany('path.to.GalleryImageResource', 'gallery', related_name='rental', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Rental.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rental'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post','put']
        fields = ['listingName','ownerName','room','price','summary']
        filtering = { "property" : ALL , "room":ALL,"price":ALL}
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()

class GalleryImageResource(ModelResource):
    rental = fields.ForeignKey(RentalResource, 'rental', full=False, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = GalleryImage.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'gallery'
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','put']
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

Comment: Only the first rent gallery is assigned a list of gallery resource( "gallery": ["/api/v1/gallery/1/", "/api/v1/gallery/2/"]). Other has the empty gallery . Also while accessing gallery api i get {"error": "The model '&lt;GalleryImage: writingDescribingData6_RfgeRIX.png&gt;' has an empty attribute 'rental' and doesn't allow a null value."}

Comment: still the same the gallery list is empty except for first rent object . I have posted a link for a clear look http://i.imgur.com/Jt2vESi.jpg

Comment: Uploaded images are saved to database but still gallery object shown an empty list.

Comment: I have to manually assign it from the admin side otherwise gallery objects are empty.

Comment: The first rental has related gallery images populated correctly. Are you sure the 2nd rental has related data?

Comment: First rental had gallery images because I manually assigned them images from admin panel so it showed otherwise it shows empty list .

Comment: I have to go to gallery table in admin panel and assign image to the rental it belongs to.

Comment: So what happens if you assign gallery images to the 2nd rental via the admin panel?

Comment: It gets populated with the assigned gallery images.

Comment: i have to select which rent should i refer for the image this way .Its not automatically popluated . http://imgur.com/L9UBSix

Comment: OK, so everything's working? Tastypie doesn't autogenerate data for you.

Comment: Do i have to tweak in models.py for autopopulating ? Because its about user registering their rent with multiple images not admin.

Comment: I think I should change my upload view.